# access params in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, parameters

I need to get access to `params` inside following block:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Discussion, namespace: :dev_panel do
  raise params.inspect
  ...
end
```

I need it exactly in there, not in `controller` or inside `action_item` whatsoever.

But I'am getting

> undefined local variable or method `params` for ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL

Does anyone know how do I do that?

## EDIT

My goal is to be able to define such two blocks in `admin/discussions.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Discussion, namespace: :dev_panel do
  belongs_to :my_active_submission, parent_class: ClientApplication
  ...
end
```

and

```
ActiveAdmin.register Discussion, namespace: :dev_panel do
  belongs_to :lead_submission, parent_class: ClientApplication
  ...
end
```

The issue with that, is that AA only treats the latter block, and behaves as there is no previous one. My bet is that issue is with namespace - I can't define two blocks of same resource and namespace.

Comment: on this scope you can't get access to `params`.

Comment: I've read on Github issues (if I'm not mistaken), sometime ago there was access to it, but not anymore. I was hoping there are some workarounds. The issue I am trying to resolve, is that I have 2 resources under dev_panel (belongs_to :lead_submission, parent_class: ClientApplication
    belongs_to :my_active_submission, parent_class: ClientApplication) and I need to be able to generate appropriate urls depending on absolute url..

Comment: this scope loading in memory only once for build responsible `controller` all other works with builded controller where you can access to params. You can simple check it. Add `puts("load once")` instead `raise params.inspect` and reload page few times. "load once" printed only once.

Comment: @Зелёный Initial problem is simple - I cant define `ActiveAdmin.register Discussion, namespace: :dev_panel` twice for different `belongs_to` blocks, because then AA just picking up the latter one, and behaves as there is only one definition.

Comment: sorry but i can't help you. I never use ActiveAdmin for complex task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try defining your Discussion with as: option? I have a model which needs to be used in a number of different context so I set up:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Discussion, as: 'ActiveDiscussion' do; end
ActiveAdmin.register Discussion, as: 'PoliticalDiscussion' do; end
```

Or you can sub-class Discussion as you needed

```
class ActiveDiscussion < Discussion; end
class PoliticalDiscussion < Discussion; end
```

And then register them to ActiveAdmin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActiveDiscussion do; end
ActiveAdmin.register PoliticalDiscussion do; end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey! thx for answer, but it goes other way around - updated the question. Thx a lot for taking a look!

Comment: Did you try using :as option? It allows you to define two different resource blocks for one model.

Comment: I eventually went this way, which is a overkill, but I had no other choice - it is insanely difficult to make AA do more sophisticated stuff as accurate, as it is with easy things

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Don't forget AA makes some part - most frequently used part maybe - insanely easy as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is technical not possible to access params at that place. The register block is only executed one at the loading and not per request.

Write down a full example, like you have access to params and we maybe find a other solution.

Comment: hey Timo! Thanks a lot for taking a look - really appreciate it as well as your help with github issues I've opened (successfully closed :)). The only one is left with forms, but I'm afraid it is buried there :(